# XmlTextWriter.WriteFullEndElement tags on the same line

Tags: xml, vb.net, tags, newline, xmltextwriter

I am using an XMLTextWriter to create an XML document dynamically (in VB.Net).
I want empty tags to appear like this - `<Tag></Tag>`
and not this - `<Tag />`

So, I am using WriteFullEndElement to end the element tag. But it is writing out the tag as -

`<Tag>`

`</Tag>`

i.e. with a newline character between the tags. The web service reading this XML rejects it due to the newline character.

How do I avoid the newline, and have both the start and end tags on the same line?

Comment: You should not be directly using `XmlTextWriter` unless you're still using .NET 1.1. Instead of using `new XmlTextWriter()`, you should use `XmlWriter.Create()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I use XmlWriter, how do I set the .Formatting and .Namespaces properties that were available with XmlTextWriter?

Answer (score 3):

Use `XmlWriterSettings`. 
Specifically, use the [NewLineHandling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling.aspx) and [NewLineChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinechars.aspx).

Following is a simple example of writing XML document in c#:

```
        XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        writerSettings.Indent = true;
        writerSettings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;


        using (XmlWriter textWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(this.fileName, writerSettings))
        {
            textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
            textWriter.WriteComment("generated file");
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
            // Populate data
            foreach (object o in someList)
            {
               textWriter.WriteStartElement(o);
               textWriter.WriteString(o);
               textWriter.WriteFullEndElement ();
            }

            textWriter.WriteFullEndElement ();
            textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            textWriter.Close(); 
        }
```

Cheers